# DB2 before trigger

Tags: database, triggers, db2, database-trigger, db2-express-c

I've got this trigger:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoIngreso
BEFORE INSERT ON Ingreso
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    UPDATE Cliente SET Nombre = 'Juan' WHERE DNI = '87366034M';
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

But db2 returns the following error:

```
The trigger "DB2INST1.ACTUALIZARSALDOINGRESO" is defined with an unsupported triggered SQL statement
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe a syntax error try `END` instead of `END@`.

Comment: @Nifriz END@ is set just for the terminator

Comment: You're right! I omitted it. Why do you reset terminator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stated in the [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) description:

> The *SQL-procedure-statement* in a BEFORE trigger cannot:
>
> Contain any INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE operations, nor invoke any routine defined with MODIFIES SQL DATA, if it is not a compound SQL (**compiled**).

Remove the `ATOMIC` clause or use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.